# Better way of asking "What country can Mount Fuji be found?"

Tags: british-english, questions

I want to ask the question:

> What country can Mount Fuji be found?

Is there a better way that I can ask this question using correct grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is Mt. Fuji situated?

In what country is Mt. Fuji situated?

Comment: I don't like *situated* in this context at all. *Situated* suggests that someone put it there, or that it chose to be there, not that is simply *is* there.

Answer (score 9):

**In** what/which country is Mount Fuji?

Comment: I prefer "which" to "what"...

Answer (score 9):

Don't be afraid to end a sentence with a preposition if that's really the most natural way to construct the sentence. You could certainly ask, "Where is Mount Fuji?", but if you're specifically wanting to know the country, "What country is Mount Fuji in?" sounds most natural.

Comment: That is the most natural way, but it is somewhat informal. In more formal writing "In what country is Mt Fuji?" is preferred. There's nothing in between in formality, except for the slightly different "Where is Mt Fuji?".

Comment: @Mitch I agree that "What country is it in?" is informal, but the OP used the word *correct*, not *formal*. I would use "In what country?" in writing. For all but the most formal situations, I would use "what country is it in?" if I were speaking.

Comment: Informal does not mean incorrect. 'Correct' is for the given context. It could be formal or informal, British English or American, Cockney or AAVE.

Comment: @Mitch Is there an appearance of disagreement I'm missing? 'Cause it seems to me that we're in agreement.

Comment: @Mitch The rule against ending a sentence with a preposition is prescriptivist, if such a rule exists at all. As Winston Churchill said, "That's the kind of pedantry up with which I will not put."

Comment: No, no, no!!  Never use a preposition to end a sentence with!!

Answer (score 1):

Where is Mt. Fuji?
In what country is Mt. Fuji?

"What country can Mount Fuji be found?" Is missing the word "in."

Answer (score 1):

> In what country can Mount Fuji be found?

As Kim points out, the original question is explicitly asking for a country.  There is no context that implicitly asks for a country, so the question must use the word "country".  If the question were changed to "Where", someone could answer "Honshu" or "Asia" or "Earth", instead of "Japan".

It is usually possible to convert a full-sentence question into a full-sentence answer by changing the word order.  The original post's question can be correctly answered by:

> Mount Fuji can be found **in** <s>what country</s> Japan.

Note that the word **in** needs to be included in the sentence, in order to make the sentence be grammatically correct.  Changing the word order back to that of a question, we get:

> In what country can Mount Fuji be found?

Because the list of countries is short enough that we could select the correct country from a list, it is also grammatically correct to use "which country" instead of "what country":

> In which country can Mount Fuji be found?

Answer (score 0):

To all who are using "Where is Mount Fuji?".

This is NOT correct. Given that we do not know the circumstances given the question we must be authoritative to the original post.

Example: 2 people are examining a distant landscape painting, named "Mount Fuji Landscape". If the questioner asks "Where is Mount Fuji?" instead of "In which country is Mount Fuji?" or "What country is Mount Fuji in?", then the answer is no longer guaranteed to match the original question. I.e. The responder could just point to Mount Fuji in the landscape painting and say "There!"